# Device not receive messages from Google GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, galaxy

I am experiencing something strange, I am developing an application that uses the Google GCM to send notifications to the user.

Everything worked fine until a couple of days, to restart my device to factory settings. the device is configured properly because I use it daily and all services are running "well"

Now I have continued to develop but to send these messages to the device fail.

when sending messages to the GCM Google APIs, this does not indicate any errors. the funny thing is that there is no change in the application and this works correctly on another device. the affected device is a Galaxy ACE (GT-5830i), the other device is a Galaxy SIII and this works without any problem, even with the emulator (Google API 2.3.3) works well.

I have no idea why this is happening with the device

#### GCM Logcat

```
07-17 10:31:59.429: D/GCMRegistrar(21586): resetting backoff for co.com.rkmax.example
07-17 10:31:59.437: V/GCMRegistrar(21586): Registering app co.com.rkmax.example of senders 123456789012
07-17 10:32:01.203: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(21586): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
07-17 10:32:01.203: V/GCMRegistrar(21586): Setting the name of retry receiver class to co.com.rkmax.example.receivers.GoogleCMReceiver
07-17 10:32:01.203: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(21586): GCM IntentService class: co.com.rkmax.example.services.ReceiverGCMService
07-17 10:32:01.210: V/GCMBaseIntentService(21586): Acquiring wakelock
07-17 10:32:01.218: V/GCMBaseIntentService(21586): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-123456789012-1
07-17 10:32:01.226: V/GCMRegistrar(21586): Registering receiver
07-17 10:32:01.226: D/GCMRegistrar(21586): resetting backoff for co.com.rkmax.example
07-17 10:32:01.234: V/GCMRegistrar(21586): Saving regId on app version 7
07-17 10:32:01.382: V/GCMBaseIntentService(21586): Releasing wakelock
```

### Update

I used the method `GCMRegistrar.unregister` and re-register and now if it works!

Comment: add tag:GCM in Log cat ,and check for logs from GCM ,and paste it with ur question

Comment: @Nargis show the update, the app work fine (register the device and send the regId to my server) but dont receive the messages when are sent

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but did u try to uninstall and re-install your application in that device...there might be some issue with the registrationId... registered with GCM..

Comment: the application was reinstalled, the device is registered and return a correctID